# Is there a Day9 for league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I watch a lot of [Day9 StarCraft 2 videos](http://day9.tv/) and have learned a lot from his excellent match analysis.

Is there any site like this – a site or video series that offers pro-level match analyses – for the League of Legends community?

Comment: why the downvote ? There is nothing subjective about this. I am simply seeking a site or video series simialr to Day9 but for LoL ... why would you vote to close this ?

Comment: closed as off topic ... wtf is that ? I tried to engage the users who voted to close with no response. This type of behavior is really annoying. I asked a gaming related question. What is Off-topic about a gaming question on arqade.com? jfc...

Comment: A popular question badge on a question that the mods tried to close immediately. I think is a perfect example of the mods being too eager to close questions.

Comment: Well I guess we'll have to agree to disagree

Comment: I would say this falls under shopping rec, except this would be useful to all league players so I'm defending it :3

Comment: @Robotsushi I could get a popular Question badge overnight on dozens of off topic or terrible questions if I could get them to stay open long enough. SE's google juice combined with a smart title goes a long way. 1100 views in nearly 6 months is *not* a convincing statistic.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Indeed the whole reason why we have Google juice is because we _don't_ do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Day9 doesn't analyze League of Legends, but here are some key components of why Day9 SCII videos are so useful.

- Charismatic presentation
- Getting viewer/community involved
- Excellent knowledge of the game
- Having a goal of what the viewer should know, presented clearly and thoroughly.

I found a YouTube channel called "SovietWaffles" who seems to do really nice analyses, so you should check that out. However, he talks sort of pedantically, so I usually turn to streamers. Look below....

[SovietWaffles Example Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QmLPSNrxOk)

I find that certain League of Legends streamers accomplish the components listed above. Note that I'm not just listing the highest ELO players - I'm listing those who I believe can analyze matches well and teach things about the game. I am a dedicated League of Legends player, but I don't know everything/everyone, so if anyone else on Arqade knows some good streamers/websites, feel free to edit my post! :)

These include:

- Scarra
- TheOddOne
- Wingsofdeathx
- Ocelote
- Guardsman Bob
- ColbyCheeZe
- Snoopeh

Depending on your skill level, some streamers might not be as helpful. As in, they'll teach you really cool stuff, but some might not be needed at, say, 1200 ELO. I would start with Guardsman Bob; I usually go to him and he has helped me in pretty much all aspects of the game. Some of these streamers also have YouTube channels.

Comment: How is this answer at all relevant to the question? The first part especially seems entirely irrelevant.

Comment: The first part is added because there aren't any analyses quite like Day9 but I'm outlining what he brings to the table and how it's similar to some streamers listed below.

Comment: The last bit is exactly what day9 is so popular. He has a purpose to each cast and it's like courses you take for on the job training: "At the end of this course, you will be able to ___, ___, and ___." He tries to do the same thing. I haven't watched many streams in a long time, but I do recall both day9 and idra playing a fair bit of LoL. Not that you'd watch idra to learn anything, but he is highly entertaining :)